Simulation Not Working after Cloth Modifier Added
I have attempted to create several projects with a cloth modifier in Blender 4.0. After I have applied the Cloth Modifier, the simulation does not work and instead only shows the mesh as it would appear as when editing. I have searched many sites and videos; however, I am unable to find a solution. Since I have had this issue with multiple projects, I am not sure where I am going wrong.
Per one suggestion for fixing the issue, I did go into edit mode and remove excess vertices (alt+H then merge by distance). However, it did not fix the issue. I have also tried changing when I apply the modifier. For example, apply Mirror modifier than the cloth modifier or apply Cloth modifier than the Mirror modifier.
Any suggestions/help will be greatly appreciated.   





Applying a modifier is a destructive process which converts any procedurally generated or simulated mesh in actual geometry. When the modifier is applied, it basically freezes the mesh in the state of the frame on which it was applied or in some cases rejects simulated data and sets the mesh back to its original state. By the way: Alt+H then merge by distance? Alt+H is unhide everything, did you have hidden vertices? If you want to merge by distance and make sure to get all duplicate/overlapping geometry, you should press A to select all.
